# PHP system, exec, passthru return code 127

Tags: php, pdf

I run this command:

```
passthru(sprintf(
    'pdftk %s fill_form %s output %s %s'
    , $pdfFilePath
    , $fdfFilePath
    , $outputFilePath
    , $editable ? '' : 'flatten'
), $resultCode);
```

And it returns 127. I checked if `pdftk` is installed by command `which pdftk` - `/snap/bin/pdftk`.

Any suggestions why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the full path to the binary you want to use. The reason that pdftk would work from command line is that it is in your enviorment $PATH variable (at least if bash, something like that for other shells).

Return code 127 is command not found, so instead of

```
'pdftk %s fill_form %s output %s %s'
```

do

```
'/snap/bin/pdftk %s fill_form %s output %s %s'
```